# Deeplearning4j on spark pipeline: What are the arguments to the org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel.predict method

Tags: java, apache-spark, deep-learning, prediction, deeplearning4j

I am trying to add sentiment analysis program written in `deeplearning4j` to Spark pipeline. Then I have to override the method `org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel. predict()` to predict using the `RNN` model I created. As I understood, the arguments to this method is a feature row and the label for the row is predicted. But, in sentiment analysis program, the features should be a 2D array because each row contains a list of list of vectors as `[[0.0011181544391649161,0.0025584171060651644,0.01754946247376411,-0.006530340570481004,0.003487414946750136,0.004426218948032432,0.00404,0.002611281607120172,0.006444432718879956,-0.012260229877306768,0.002399729592556043]]`

But I get a 1D array as`[0.003356837383,0.0074654373,...]` as the input of predict method. Can you explain why this happens and can you explain the what are the arguments to the predict method?

Comment: You should be more clear, you should try to show a reproducible example, and more when you say you modified the spark core.

Comment: Just to mention this: You can also ask this on [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Our usingrnns page may give you some ideas:
http://deeplearning4j.org/usingrnns

The internal representation for dl4j will need to match this anyways.